# What's the different of XWPFTable table = doc.createTable and new XWPFTable(CTTbl, IBody)?

Tags: apache-poi

I am now generating a word report using POI word (XWPF),and there are many tables and paragraphs in my report. I want to reduce the coupling between methods, so I create a table or paragraph inside method and return it, then I want to add it to document. I know document has not the add method, but I mean I want to focus on content only and reduce the coupling between document and paragraph(or table). Below is my code I want to be in next:

```
    private XWPFParagraph getParagraph(String string) {
            XWPFParagraph paragraph = new XWPFParagraph(CTP, IBody);
            XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun();
            run.setText(string);
            return paragraph; 
        }   
    public void generateReport(XWPFDocument document){   
     document.add( getParagraph("aaaaaaaaaaaa"););
   }
```

my question is:first, what is the different between:
`XWPFParagraph = document.createParagraph` and `XWPFParagraph paragraph = new XWPFParagraph(CTP, IBody);` or 
     `XWPFTable table = doc.createTable() and new XWPFTable(CTTbl, IBody)`
second, what I should do if I want to document.add(new XWPFparagraph(CTP,IBoby)) like I want to be above. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Avoid the CT classes and methods that expose them as much as possible. They could change as they are an artifact of XMLBeans (which is old and looking for a replacement). In addition, these methods will be deprecated and removed from the API as it matures and access to the CT classes becomes unnecessary. They also require you to know a lot more about the internals of the docx format and how it is constructed. `XWPFDocument.createParagraph()` and `XWPFDocument.createTable()` create paragraphs and tables inside the XWPFDocument without you having to know about those structures. These are the appropriate methods to use.